# What are Vertex Array Objects?

Tags: opengl, vbo, vertex-array, vao

I am just starting to learn OpenGL today from this tutorial: http://openglbook.com/the-book/
I got to chapter 2, where I draw a triangle, and I understand everything except VAOs (is this acronym OK?). The tutorial has this code:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VaoId);
glBindVertexArray(VaoId);
```

While I understand that the code is necessary, I have no clue what it does. Although I never use VaoId past this point (except to destroy it), the code does not function without it. I am assuming this is because it is required to be bound, but I don't know why. Does this exact code just need to be part of every OpenGL program? The tutorial explains VAOs as:

> A Vertex Array Object (or VAO) is an object that describes how the vertex attributes are stored in a Vertex Buffer Object (or VBO). This means that the VAO is not the actual object storing the vertex data, but the descriptor of the vertex data. Vertex attributes can be described by the glVertexAttribPointer function and its two sister functions glVertexAttribIPointer and glVertexAttribLPointer, the first of which we’ll explore below.

I don't understand how the VAO describes the vertex attributes. I have not described them in any way. Does it get the information from the glVertexAttribPointer? I guess this must be it. Is the VAO simply a destination for the information from glVertexAttribPointer?

On a side note, is the tutorial I am following acceptable? Is there anything I should watch out for or a better tutorial to follow?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

"Vertex Array Object" is brought to you by the OpenGL ARB Subcommittee for Silly Names.

Think of it as a geometry object. (As an old time SGI Performer programmer, I call them geosets.) The instance variables/members of the object are your vertex pointer, normal pointer, color pointer, attrib N pointer, ...

When a VAO is first bound, you assign these members by calling

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); glVertexPointer...;
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY); glNormalPointer...;
```

and so on. Which attributes are enabled and the pointers you supply are stored in the VAO.

After that when you bind the VAO again, all the those attributes and pointers also become current. So one `glBindVertexArray` call is equivalent to all the code previously needed to set up all the attributes. It's handy for passing geometry around between functions or methods without having to create your own structs or objects.

(One time setup, multiple use is the easiest way to use VAOs, but you can also change attributes just by binding it and doing more enable/pointer calls. VAOs are not constants.)

More info in response to Patrick's questions:

The default for a newly created VAO is that it's empty (AFAIK). No geometry at all, not even vertexes, so if you try to draw it, you'll get an OpenGL error. This is reasonably sane, as in "initialize everything to False/NULL/zero".

You only need to `glEnableClientState` when you set things up. The VAO remembers the enable/disable state for each pointer.

Yes the VAO will store `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttrib`. The old vertex, normal, color, ... arrays are the same as attribute arrays, vertex == #0 and so on.

Comment: '"Vertex Array Object" is brought to you by the OpenGL ARB Subcommittee for Silly Names.' Yes, such a silly name for an **object** that stores **vertex** **array** bindings.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, calling `glGenVertexArrays(1, &VaoId);` and `glBindVertexArray(VaoId);` creates a VAO with sane defaults to save you from `glEnableClientState`? Or am I completely misunderstanding you? In the future will I most likely use a lot of `glEnableClientState`?

Comment: Also, are VAOs at all related to `glVertexAttribPointer`

Comment: Please add some information about the use of generic vertex attributes for the people who are using the core profile.

Comment: @NicolBolas A better name would be `VertexArrayMacro` or something similar.

Comment: According to the OpenGL wiki, glVertexAttrib is *NOT* part of VAO state (unlike glVertexAttribPointer, which is), but is instead a context state value.

Comment: @NicolBolas "Vertex Array Object" is an awful name. It is about *binding data to attributes*. It is not about array of vertices, as the name implies. There is no reference to bindings or attributes in the name, and since "vertex array" is a separated concept itself, it makes understanding even harder. IMHO,
 "(Vertex) Attributes Binding Object" is easier to understand. Even Geometry Object is better: I don't like it, but at least it is not overloaded.

Comment: @AkiRoss: "*It is not about array of vertices, as the name implies.*" But it *is* about arrays of vertices. Those buffers it stores contain arrays of vertices. A VAO describes how to interpret that storage as arrays of vertex data. It describes which arrays go to which vertex attributes. And so forth. VAO is a perfectly legitimate name.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry it may be legitimate but *it is* an awful name.  As can be seen by this question and comments, VAOs seem to cause more confusion than any other fundamental GL concept.  Why would that be?  I don't think a VAO is inherently complex, could it possibly be simply that it has an unclear name?

Comment: @Ash: No, it's because it has a terrible *API*. Who is it that gets confused about how VAOs work? It's people who use VAOs with pre-DSA functions. Nobody who uses the DSA functions (or even the `glVertexAttribBinding` APIs) has any problem understanding how VAOs work or how to use them. It's all the fault of `glVertexAttribPointer`, `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)`, and their ilk. Couple that with terrible tutorials that encourage copying/pasting of code without understanding it, and here we are.

Comment: @Hugh: "*if you try to draw it, you'll get an OpenGL error*" Wrong. It is perfectly valid to render with an empty VAO. Your vertex attributes will use constant values, but there will not be an OpenGL error from it. Also: "*Yes the VAO will store glEnableVertexAttribArray and glVertexAttrib.*" It will *not* store `glVertexAttrib` state. It stores vertex ***array*** data, and `glVertexAttrib` state are not part of vertex arrays. They're context state.

Answer (score 33):

I always think about VAO as an array of data buffers used by OpenGL. Using modern OpenGL you will create a VAO and Vertex Buffer Objects.

[image]

```
//vaoB is a buffer
glGenVertexArrays(1, vaoB); //creates one VAO
glBindVertexArray(vao.get(0));
glGenBuffers(vbo.length, vbo, 0); //vbo is a buffer
glBindVertexArray(vao.get(1));
glGenBuffers(vbo1.length, vbo1, 0); //vbo1 is a buffer
glBindVertexArray(vao.get(2));
glGenBuffers(vbo2.length, vbo2, 0); //vbo2 is a buffer
```

The next step is to bind data to a buffer:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertBuf.limit()*4, vertBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW); //vertf buf is a floatbuffer of vertices
```

At this point OpenGL Sees:

[image]

Now we can use glVertexAttribPointer to tell OpenGL what the data in the buffer represents:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //bind VBO at 0
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0); //each vertex has 3 components of size GL_FLOAT with 0 stride (space) between them and the first component starts at 0 (start of data)
```

[image]

OpenGL now has the data in the buffer and knows how the data is organized into vertices. The same process can be applied to texture coordinates etc but for texture coordinates there would be two values.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,coordBuf.limit()*4, coordBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Next you can bind texture and draw arrays, you will want to create a Vert and Frag shader, compile and attach it to a program (not included here).

```
glActiveTexture(textureID); //bind our texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,6); //in this case 6 indices are used for two triangles forming a square
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer and the diagrams are useful -- however the code examples aren't. In fact they are more confusing than useful. In the 1st example you're calling glGenVertexArrays() on a buffer object? Then repeated glGenBuffers() with 3 arguments? Not sure what it's supposed to mean or do but it simply does not make sense to me, let alone compile.

Answer (score 12):

Vertex Array Objects are like **macros** in word processing programs and the like.  A good description is found [here](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial32/tutorial32.html).

Macros just *remember* the actions you did, such as activate this attribute, bind that buffer, etc.  When you call `glBindVertexArray( yourVAOId )`, it simply **replays** those attribute pointer bindings and buffer bindings.

So your next call to draw uses whatever was bound by the VAO.

VAO's don't store *vertex data*.  No.  The vertex data is stored in a vertex *buffer* or in an array of client memory.

Comment: -1: They are not like macros. If they were, then binding a new VAO would not disable the vertex arrays enabled by a previous VAO, unless the new VAO has "recorded" you *explicitly* disabling those arrays. VAOs, like *all* OpenGL objects, hold *state*, not commands. Commands simply *change* state, but objects come with default state set. That's why binding a newly created VAO will *always* disable all attributes.

Answer (score 8):

*VAO is an object that represents the vertex fetch stage of the OpenGL pipeline and is used to supply input to the vertex shader.*

You can create vertex array object like this

```
GLuint vao;
glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

First let' do a simple example. Consider such an input parameter in a shader code

```
layout (location = 0) in vec4 offset; // input vertex attribute
```

To fill in this attribute we can use

```
glVertexAttrib4fv(0, attrib); // updates the value of input attribute 0
```

Although the vertex array object stores these static attribute values for
you, it can do a lot more.

After creating vertex array object we can start filling in its state. We will ask OpenGL to fill it automatically using the data stored in a buffer object that we supply. Each vertex attribute gets to fetch data from a buffer bound to one of several vertex buffer bindings. For this end we use `glVertexArrayAttribBinding(GLuint vao, GLuint attribindex, GLuint bindingindex)`. Also we use the `glVertexArrayVertexBuffer()` function to bind a buffer to one of the vertex buffer bindings. We use the `glVertexArrayAttribFormat()` function to describe the layout and format of the data, and finally we enable automatic filling of the attribute by calling `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`.

When a vertex attribute is enabled, OpenGL will feed data to the vertex shader based on the format and location information you’ve provided with
`glVertexArrayVertexBuffer()` and `glVertexArrayAttribFormat()`. When
the attribute is disabled, the vertex shader will be provided with the static information you provide with a call to `glVertexAttrib*()`.

```
// First, bind a vertex buffer to the VAO
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, buffer, 0, sizeof(vmath::vec4));

// Now, describe the data to OpenGL, tell it where it is, and turn on automatic
// vertex fetching for the specified attribute
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);

glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 0);
```

And code in a shader

```
layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
```

After all you need to call to `glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao)`.

---

You can read [OpenGL SuperBible](http://www.openglsuperbible.com/) to understand it better.

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to understand this as well and now that I think I do, it would be prudent to post a code example aimed at
people less familiar with OpenGL architecture, as I found the previous examples not very illuminating and most tutorials
just tell you to copy paste the code without explaining it.

(This is in C++ but the code can be easily translated to C)

In this example, we'll be rendering a rectangle, which has 4 vertices. Each vertex has a position (vec3, xyz), texture coordinate (vec2, uv) and color attribute (vec4, rgba).

I think it's cleanest to separate each attribute into their own array:

```cpp
float positions[] = {
    +0.5, +0.5, 0,
    +0.5, -0.5, 0,
    -0.5, -0.5, 0,
    -0.5, +0.5, 0
};

float colors[] = {
    1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1
};

float tex_coords[] = {
    0, 0,
    0, 1,
    1, 1,
    1, 0
};
```

Our vertex array object will describe the four vertices with these properties.

First, we need to create the vertex array:

```cpp
GLuint vertex_array;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array);
```

Each vertex array has a number of buffers, these can be thought of as properties of the array. Each vertex array has an
arbitrary number of "slots" for the buffers. Along with which buffer is in which slot, it saves the CPU-side pointer to
the data for the buffer, and the CPU-side datas format. We need to make OpenGL aware of both which slot to use, where the
data is, and how it is formatted.

The buffers slots are indexed, so the first buffer is index 0, the second is 1, etc.
These locations correspond to the `layout` defined in the vertex shader:

```c
// vertex shader
std::string _noop_vertex_shader_source = R"(
    #version 420

    layout (location = 0) in vec3 _position_3d; // slot 0: xyz
    layout (location = 1) in vec4 _color_rgba;  // slot 1: rgba
    layout (location = 2) in vec2 _tex_coord;   // slot 2: uv

    out vec2 _vertex_tex_coord;
    out vec4 _vertex_color_rgba;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(_position_3d.xy, 1, 1);  // forward position to fragment shader
        _vertex_color_rgba = _color_rgba;   // forward color to fragment shader
        _vertex_tex_coord = _tex_coord;     // forward tex coord to fragment shader
    }
)";
```

We see that the position property is at location 0, the color property at 1 and the tex coords at 2. We'll store these
for clarity:

```cpp
// property locations from our shader
const auto vertex_pos_location = 0;
const auto vertex_color_location = 1;
const auto vertex_tex_coord_location = 2;
```

We now need to tell OpenGL the information about each buffer outlined above:

```cpp
// bind the array, this makes OpenGL aware that we are modifying it with future calls
glBindVertexArray(vertex_array);

// create the position buffer
glGenBuffers(1, &position_buffer);

// bind the buffer so opengl knows we are currently operating on it
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, position_buffer);

// tell opengl where the data pointer is
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(positions), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// tell opengl how the data is formatted
glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_pos_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);

// tell opengl that this slot should be used
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_pos_location);
```

Here, we generate a buffer that will hold our position data. For `glVertexAttribPointer`, we choose the
correct location, 3 elements (as the positions are xyz coordinates), and no offset or stride.
Because we have a separate array for all our properties, we can leave both as 0.

Similar to the position, we generate and fill the buffers for the color and tex coord property:

```cpp
// color
glGenBuffers(1, &color_buffer); // generate
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, color_buffer); // bind
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // set pointer
glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_color_location, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0); // set data format
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_color_location); // enable slot

// tex coords
glGenBuffers(1, &tex_coord_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tex_coord_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(tex_coords), tex_coords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_tex_coord_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_tex_coord_location);
```

Where we chose 4 elements for the colors because they are in RGBA format and 2 for the tex coords for obvious reasons.

The last thing we need to render a vertex array is an *element buffer*. These can be thought of as a list of
indices that define which order the vertices will be rendered in. For us, we want to render the
rectangle as two tris in a triangle fan, so we choose the following element buffer:

```cpp
// vertex order
static uint32_t indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3
};

glGenBuffers(1, &element_buffer); // generate
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, element_buffer); // bind
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW) // set pointer
```

We do not need to enable the element buffers slot, it is separate from the vertex array. We don't have to specify the format of the elements buffer here, that will be done during `glDrawElements` in the render step.

So why all this? All these functions tell OpenGL where to look for the data for the vertices. Specifying the pointers to
the correct buffer data and their layout, if we now bind the vertex array during a render step:

```cpp
glUseProgram(shader.get_program_id()); // shader program with our vertex shader

glBindVertexArray(vertex_array);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, element_buffer);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Where 6 is the number of elements in the element buffer.

This is all that's needed to correctly update the `in` values in the vertex shader. OpenGL will move the data from
our CPU-side `positions`, `colors` and `tex_coords` into the correct locations 0, 1 and 2 of the vertex shader respectively.
We don't need to bind anything else, the vertex array remembers what we gave it and does it for us, which is why it's convenient and should be preferred in modern OpenGL.

---

In summary:

Each vertex array has n buffers for arbitrary properties and 1 element buffer. For each property / buffer, we need to

a) generate it (`glGenBuffers`)
b) bind it (`glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`)
c) tell OpenGL where the data is located in RAM (`glBufferData`)
d) tell OpenGL how the data is formatted (`glVertexAttribPointer`)
e) tell OpenGL to use that slot (`glEnableVertexAttribArray`)

for the element buffer, we only need to generate it, bind it to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, then tell opengl
where the data is.

Hopefully that helped shed some light on things. I'm almost positive there will be factual errors in this post as
I'm also mostly new to OpenGL but this was the way I conceptualized it to get my code working.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I've been scouring the internet looking for a simple explanation like this for days.