# I don't understand how glGenVertexArrays and glBindVertexArray works

Tags: c++, opengl, vao

This small piece of code makes me confused.

```
GLuint VAO;

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
```

From what I know, glGenVertexArrays generates 1 name/ID and stores it into the variable VAO. What I don't understand is when I use the function glBindVertexArray. When it binds, it binds the name/ID with the VAO object. Where is the VAO object? The only item passed into glBindVertexArray is the VAO integer object but I thought that the VAO integer object only stores the name/ID of the VAO. I don't think that the VAO integer object is the actual VAO object itself. If it isn't so, where is the VAO object that it will bind the name/ID to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are Vertex Array Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821336/what-are-vertex-array-objects)