# vertex buffer object and data buffers [opengl]

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to figure out how to use multiple buffers associated to a single vertex array object on the basis of one buffer per "object model" (e.g. verticies, normal, textures). **To make it very simple in the sample code that follows I have couple objects composed of just one triangles (3 vertices) and associated colors**. Buffer element indexed by ArrayBuffer1 receive the vertex coords (homogeneous coords) and an RGBA  color vectors. Same for Buffer element indexed by ArrayBuffer2.

The vertex shader is a passthrough as following

```
    #version 400 core

    layout( location = 0 ) in vec4 vPosition;
    layout( location = 1 ) in vec4 vColor;
    out vec4 color;
    void
    main()
    {
        color= vColor;
        gl_Position = vPosition;
    }
```

The fragment shader is a passthroug has well

```
    #version 450 core

    in vec4 color;
    out vec4 fColor;

    void main()
    {
        fColor = color; 
    }
```

I d like to pass on data with one buffer per object grouping vertex attributes in the same buffer.

I can't figure  how to raw these 2 objects.
Here is the client code (init part)

```
    enum VertexDim { xDim, yDim, zDim, wDim, NumDim};
    enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs };
    enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer1, ArrayBuffer2, NumBuffers };
    enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0, vColor=1 };

    GLuint  VAOs[NumVAOs];
    GLuint  Buffers[NumBuffers];

    const GLuint  NumVertices = 6;
    const GLuint curDim= NumDim;
    // first triangle 
    GLfloat  static_vertices1[NumVertices/2][NumDim] = {
        { -0.90f, -0.90f, 0.5f, 1}, {  0.85f, -0.90f, 0.3f, 1 }, { -0.90f,  0.85f, 0.0f, 1 }  // Triangle 1
    };
    // second triangle
    GLfloat  static_vertices2[NumVertices/2][NumDim] = {
        {  0.90f, -0.85f, -0.1f, 1 }, {  0.90f,  0.90f, -0.5f, 1 }, { -0.85f,  0.90f, -0.8f, 1 }   // Triangle 2
    };
    // a base color from which to compute different vertex colors
    GLfloat infColor_value[4]= {0.9f, 0.7f, 0.5f, 1.0f};  

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // init
    //

    void
    init( void )
    {   
        const unsigned int n=NumVertices/2;
        GLfloat infColor_values1[n][curDim];    
        GLfloat infColor_values2[n][curDim];  
        // compute different vertex colors from base color   infColor_value
        // .. loop over    infColor_values1 and infColor_values2

        ShaderInfo  shaders[] =
        {
            { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "media/shaders/triangles/triangles2.vert" },
            { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "media/shaders/triangles/triangles2.frag" },
            { GL_NONE, NULL }
        };
        // LoadShaders is a wrapper to load, compile code and link shaders
        GLuint program = LoadShaders( shaders );
        if( program == 0) { std::cerr<<"shader program failed to build" << std::endl; }
        glUseProgram( program );

        glGenVertexArrays( NumVAOs, VAOs );
        glBindVertexArray( VAOs[Triangles] );
        glCreateBuffers( NumBuffers, Buffers );

        // vertex 1
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer1] );
        glNamedBufferData( Buffers[ArrayBuffer1], sizeof(static_vertices1)+sizeof(infColor_values1) , NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glNamedBufferSubData( Buffers[ArrayBuffer1], 0,  sizeof(static_vertices1), static_vertices1);
        glNamedBufferSubData( Buffers[ArrayBuffer1], sizeof(static_vertices1),  sizeof(infColor_values1), infColor_values1);

        GLuint64 offset = 0;
        glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, NumDim, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
        offset = sizeof(static_vertices1);
        glVertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *)offset );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

        // vertex 2 
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer2] );       
        glNamedBufferData( Buffers[ArrayBuffer2], sizeof(static_vertices2)+sizeof(infColor_values2) , NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glNamedBufferSubData( Buffers[ArrayBuffer2], 0,  sizeof(static_vertices2), static_vertices1);
        glNamedBufferSubData( Buffers[ArrayBuffer2], sizeof(static_vertices2),  sizeof(infColor_values2), infColor_values2);

        offset = 0;
        glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, NumDim, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
        offset = sizeof(static_vertices2);
        glVertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *)offset );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( vColor );
        
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
```

and here follows the code to render

---

```
void
display( void )
{
    static const float black[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black);

    glBindVertexArray( VAOs[Triangles] );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES,  0, NumVertices );
    glBindVertexArray(0);    
}
```

---

to sum it up : **how to store an object vertices attributes in a single buffer and still display multiple objects ?**
I could fetch verything in the same sub buffers (one for vertex coord, one for vetex colors) but I can't come up wit ha solution where I would sparate the obejcts to render.

I ve read close answers ( [Architecture to draw many different objects in OpenGL](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83567/architecture-to-draw-many-different-objects-in-opengl) [What are Vertex Array Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821336/what-are-vertex-array-objects) ) related to this question yet it does not answer my question.

Comment: "*how to store all object vertices attribute in a same buffer and still display multiple objects ?*" I thought you were asking about using *multiple* buffers? That's what your first sentence says: "how to use multiple buffers associated to a single vertex array object". Which is it?

Comment: @NicolBolas rephrased to "how to store an object vertices attribute in a single buffer" ...

Comment: That doesn't really clear things up, as your first sentence is still talking about "multiple buffers".

Comment: The vertex array object stores the vertex specifications of a mesh. So you need 1 vertex array object per mesh. Bind the VAO before you define the vertex attribute data. Bind the VAO again before you draw the mesh.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I answered folloing your remark. IT works that way

Comment: @NicolBolas i might not have been quite accurate with the vocabulary I should have used  subset of buffer objects may be as mentionned in the refernce documentation [glNamedBufferSubData — updates a subset of a buffer object's data store](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a VAO for each object made it following @Rabbid76 advice

change for the init code

```
    enum Buffer_IDs { Mesh, NumBuffers };

    //....


        // triangle 1
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers1[Mesh] );
        glNamedBufferData( Buffers1[Mesh], sizeof(static_vertices1)+sizeof(infColor_values1) , NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glNamedBufferSubData( Buffers1[Mesh], 0,  sizeof(static_vertices1), static_vertices1);
        glNamedBufferSubData( Buffers1[Mesh], sizeof(static_vertices1),  sizeof(infColor_values1), infColor_values1);

        GLuint64 offset = 0;
        glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, NumDim, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
        offset = sizeof(static_vertices1);
        glVertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *)offset );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // triangle 2
        glBindVertexArray( VAOs[Triangle2] );
        glCreateBuffers( NumBuffers, Buffers2 );
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers2[Mesh] );
        glNamedBufferData( Buffers2[Mesh], sizeof(static_vertices2)+sizeof(infColor_values2) , NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glNamedBufferSubData( Buffers2[Mesh], 0,  sizeof(static_vertices2), static_vertices2);
        glNamedBufferSubData( Buffers2[Mesh], sizeof(static_vertices2),  sizeof(infColor_values2), infColor_values2);

        offset = 0;
        glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, NumDim, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
        offset = sizeof(static_vertices2);
        glVertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *)offset );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( vColor );
```

change for the render code

```
    void
    display( void )
    {
        static const float black[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black);

        glBindVertexArray( VAOs[Triangle1] );
        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES,  0, NumVertices/2 );
        glBindVertexArray( VAOs[Triangle2] );
        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES,  0, NumVertices/2 );   
        glBindVertexArray(0);    
    }
```