# QOpenGLWidgets do not draw anything in application but draw normally in RenderDoc Frame Capture

Tags: c++, qt, qtopengl, renderdoc

I made a Qt Application to preview 3D model. I use `QOpenGLWidget` to draw the triangles, with the core profile OpenGL v3.3. The shader compiler does not output any errors, and application run successfully, and everything seems like work.

Here are the general steps:

- Before application creating, set the default format to version 3.3 with Core profile:

```cpp
auto format = QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat();
format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
format.setVersion(3, 3);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

- For previewing multiple models simultaneously, use shared context attribute:

```cpp
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts);
```

- To simplify the description and code, I put a simple shader (called 'Skybox' in my application, to draw a gradient sky) as follows, although still does not work normally yet:

```c
//////////////////
// Vertex Shader
//////////////////

#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

out vec3 fragPos;

void main()
{
    fragPos = aPos;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}

////////////////////
// Fragment Shader
////////////////////

#version 330 core
in vec3 fragPos;
out vec4 fragCol;

uniform float _fov_rad;
uniform float _pitch;
uniform vec3 _sky;
uniform vec3 _ground;

void main()
{
    vec3 down   = (_pitch - _fov_rad * 0.5) * (_sky - _ground) + _ground;
    vec3 up     = (_pitch + _fov_rad * 0.5) * (_sky - _ground) + _ground;
    float pitch = (fragPos.y + 1.0) * 0.5;
    fragCol = vec4( pitch * (up - down) + down, 1.0) ;
}
```

- The rendering code:

```cpp
///////////////////////////
//// in 'initializeGL' ////
///////////////////////////

//... some other initializations

makeCurrent();
// prepare data
QVector4 vertices = {
    {-1.f, -1.f, .0f},
    { 1.f, -1.f, .0f},
    {-1.f,  1.f, .0f},
    { 1.f,  1.f, .0f},
};
unsigned int indices[6] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 1, 3
};
// creating buffers
auto vbo_v = std::make_shared<QOpenGLBuffer>(QOpenGLBuffer::Type::VertexBuffer);
if (!vbo_v->create()) {
    qDebug() << "TriangleData::TriangleData>> vbo_v create failed";
}
vbo_v->bind();
vbo_v->setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::UsagePattern::StaticDraw);
vbo_v->allocate(mesh->vertices.data(), mesh->verticesNum() * sizeof(QVector3D));

auto vbo_n = std::make_shared<QOpenGLBuffer>(QOpenGLBuffer::Type::VertexBuffer);
if (!vbo_n->create()) {
    qDebug() << "TriangleData::TriangleData>> vbo_n create failed";
}
vbo_n->bind();
vbo_n->setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::UsagePattern::StaticDraw);
vbo_n->allocate(mesh->normals.data(), mesh->verticesNum() * sizeof(QVector3D));

auto ibo = std::make_shared<QOpenGLBuffer>(QOpenGLBuffer::Type::IndexBuffer);
if (!ibo->create()) {
    qDebug() << "TriangleData::TriangleData>> ibo create failed";
}
ibo->bind();
ibo->setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::UsagePattern::StaticDraw);
ibo->allocate(mesh->indices.data(), mesh->facesNum() * 3 * sizeof(unsigned int));

... 

doneCurrent();

//////////////////////
//// in 'paintGL' ////
//////////////////////

QOpenGLFunctions f(QOpenGLContext::currentContext());
f.glClearColor(178.f/255.f, 168.f/255.f, 70.f/255.f, 1.0f);
f.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

QOpenGLShaderProgram* sprog = m_skyShader->sprog;
sprog->bind();
sprog->setUniformValue("_fov_rad", 70.f * 3.1415926f / 180.f);
sprog->setUniformValue("_sky", {.7f,.8f,.9f});
sprog->setUniformValue("_ground", {.1f,.2f,.3f});
sprog->setUniformValue("_pitch", .0f);

// binding attribute
vbo_v->bind();
sprog->enableAttributeArray(0);
sprog->setAttributeBuffer(0, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, 0);

vbo_n->bind();
sprog->enableAttributeArray(1);
sprog->setAttributeBuffer(1, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, 0);

ibo->bind();

// drawing
f.glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 2 * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

If it worked, the result should look like this (the nice gradient background):

[image: Expected Result]

But it looks like this (only the clear color):

[image: Actual Result]

The same cpp code, and the similar shader (but in compatible profile) worked well.

For some reason it should run in core profile. Anyway, I still want to figure out why this weird problem occurred.

So I compiled `RenderDoc` from source to get Mac `RenderDoc`, and capture this application to point out the problem.

When I used `RenderDoc` (MAC) to launch this and capture the frames, it did render normally as below:

[image: RenderDoc Capture]

Here is the capture, saved as an `.rdc` file:

[RDC file](https://github.com/Kpure1000/ImageRepository/raw/master/capture1.rdc)

**Environment:**

- HD:       MacBook Air M1 2020
- OS:       MacOS 12.6.3
- Qt:       6.5.0
- Compiler: Clang arm 64bit

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly set the depth buffer size on `format`, e.g. `format.setDepthBufferSize(24)`?

Comment: Yes I tried but still not work (format.setDepthBufferSize(24))

Comment: **Unrelated note:** the information you added as Qt version, is actually the version of Qt used to build you Qt Creator, not the version you're using for your project.

Comment: Thanks! I found the actual version used in my project is 6.5.0 in Build Settings. It must be hard to read due to my terrible grammar... I really appreciate such detailed edit suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible Reason

In `RenderDoc`, I found that after all render pass, a `VAO` ([Vertex Array Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821336/what-are-vertex-array-objects)) called `defaultVAO` was bound in `CGLFLushDrawable()`.

But in my render pass, there was no `VAO` bound, because I follow along the old code with Compatible Profile OpenGL.

This might cause no actual buffers being flushed to draw in real application environment; but in `renderDoc` environment, it might be rendered by `renderDoc`'s flushed normally.

---

#### Solution

I use `QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core` to create a vao when initialized for every render pass:

```cpp
// 'RenderAPI' is my own redundant API
...
struct RenderAPI {
...
    QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core f_330C;
...
};
...
// in initialization QOpenGLWidget
auto &f = RenderAPI::getInstance()->f_330C;
f.glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
```

And bind the specific `VAO` before setting vertex attribute:

```cpp
auto &f = RenderAPI::getInstance()->f_330C;
f.glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

[image]